# More efficient or shorter way to write this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, relational-database

Okay so my database works like this. Each Company has a list of Users that relate to that Company. Each User has a list of Clients that relate to that User. I need a way to efficiently list all of the Clients that are indirectly associated with that Company (a Client is only ever associated with its User's Company). This is what I've come up with so far:

```
 List<User> users = db.Users.Where(u => u.CompanyId == 1 /*this company's Id*/).ToList();
            List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                clients.AddRange(user.Clients);
            }
```

Is this the best way or is there a way in which to use Linq to SQL in one line to optimise the code?

Comment: For working pieces of code you need to optimize (in time and/or readability), you should head to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: This might get closed as stub code at Code Review because it is such a small snippet.  You should post at lease the entire method, and maybe a section of interrelated methods/classes.

Comment: Linq simplifies code; it does not generally optimize it.  For example, your sample code will probably perform better than calling `SelectMany(...).ToList()` because the list will grow more efficiently.

Comment: @phoog it depends if the collection is an IEnumerable or IQueryable. 
In that case it seems that the code works with IQueryable. The initial code will make n+1 query to the database whereas the SelectMany will make only 1 query.

Comment: @CyrilDURAND True enough.  When I wrote that comment, I was thinking of linq to objects (IEnumerable), not linq to sql.  I don't work much with IQueryables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go the other direction, and use `SelectMany`, like this:

```
var clients = company.Users.SelectMany(u => u.Clients)
```

Of course, you do need to fetch the company object first (instead of going off the ID).

Comment: I wasn't at all aware of the .SelectMany() function, thank you for enlightening me. Are there any drawbacks to this method?

Comment: @barnacle.m Not that I know of. Its purpose-built for flattening collections :)

Comment: `a.SelectMany(x => x.B)` [works](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#8f3471331178bcb0) as a nested `foreach` - the outer loop iterates over `A`, the inner loop iterates over `x.B` and `yield return`s each value in `B`, so there are no drawbacks inherently from using it.